# How to make all file shares without passwords?

Tags: windows, permissions, samba

New to ubuntu. I'm trying to access it from windows. Shares I created from the desktop worked fine but trying to share my ext hdd using the same method didn't work. I researched it and found you need to configure samba for it. I did that but now windows asks for credentials and they don't work. Can you either tell me if I'm entering them wrong, or (preferably) how to set samba shares never to ask for credentials?

On ubuntu (username = username, password = password).
From windows I tried entering:

username: \username
password: password

username: \ubuntumachinename\username
password: password

username: \workgroupname\username
password: password

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

From my samba config, this makes a public share

```
[videos]
comment = Videos
path = /media/external/videos
public = yes
writable = yes
create mask = 0660
directory mask = 0770
force user = mythtv
force group = mythtv
browseable = yes
```